# How to add a main menu option in Mantis BT

Tags: mantis

I am confused either to create a new plugin or make some changes to the source code to add a menu option.

What should i do to add a main menu option in Mantis BT?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a menu item pointing to a static link, the easiest way to do this is via configuration; add the following code to your *config_inc.php* file:

```
$g_main_menu_custom_options = array(
    array( 'Link text', ANYONE, 'http://example.com' ),
);
```

Please refer to the [Admin guide](https://mantisbt.org/docs/master-1.3.x/en-US/Admin_Guide/html-desktop/#admin.config.html) for details.